# Suppressing "use of the 'X' attribute is a C++17 extension" warnings

Tags: c++, qt, g++

I'm using Qt Creator and I have `CONFIG += c++17` in my .pro file, and I'm using the `nodiscard` attribute where appropriate. However, the compiler still needlessly warns that `use of the '[[nodiscard]]' attribute is a C++17 extension`.

Is there a way to suppress that particular warning? Or even all warnings of the type "X is a C++XX extension"? I've looked everywhere for a flag to include in `CXXFLAGS` without success.

I'm using Qt Creator version 4.9.2 and g++ version 8.3.0

Comment: Add the version of Qt Creator and compiler

Comment: Sorry. Qt Creator 4.9.2 and G++ 8.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Qt 5.12 you can use config flag `CONFIG += c++17`

Before Qt 5.12 you need to add compiler flags through qmake flags: `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17` for GCC & MinGW and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /std:c++latest` or `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /std:c++17` <- depends on MSVC compiler you are using.

Here is [Qt qmake manual variable reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#) for more info

And Gerrit code review of task [QTBUG-67527](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/242384) for even more info

**After you have added this flags:**

1. run qmake on the project again
2. clean your project. (delete shadow build folder if necessary)
3. rebuild your project